# In ASPNET 6 running on Azure App Services, User.Identity.Name is null because the claim uses the wrong name

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

After migrating a Blazor Server App project from dotnet 5 to dotnet 6, I'm encountering a weird problem with authentication.

The app is using local username and password for authentication.

In ConfigureServices(), we have

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>
            (options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                // attempt to force name claim to "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" 
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name;
            })
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddUserManager<UserManager<IdentityUser>>()
            .AddRoleManager<AspNetRoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Now, this has been working fine in .net 5, both in the dev environment, and also in Azure App Services (windows / iis )

After upgrading to .net 6, the following is observed:

- Dev environment  (launched using "Project" ): Everything works as before (including authentication)
- Prod environment (Azure App Service) : Authentication is broken. When someone logs in, 'Identity.IsAuthenticated' is true, but 'Identity.Name' is null.

I traced the problem to the following:

- in Dev, the claims are as follows:

```
    2022-05-17 12:46:54.190 +12:00 [INF] Claim http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier  = 7f041757-3aad-4221-971a-729598c1d81e
    2022-05-17 12:46:54.190 +12:00 [INF] Claim http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name  = superadmin@local
    2022-05-17 12:46:54.190 +12:00 [INF] Claim http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress  = someone@somewhere.com
    2022-05-17 12:46:54.190 +12:00 [INF] Claim AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp  = OJLEYFWG4JE4ND5NRPTRT4JVCVEE2ANR
    2022-05-17 12:46:54.191 +12:00 [INF] Claim http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role  = SuperAdmin
    2022-05-17 12:46:54.191 +12:00 [INF] Claim amr  = pwd
```

But in Prod (Azure App services), the claims are as follows

```
2022-05-17 01:16:12.467 +00:00 [INF] Claim http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier  = 7f041757-3aad-4221-971a-729598c1d81e
2022-05-17 01:16:12.468 +00:00 [INF] **Claim name  = superadmin@local**
2022-05-17 01:16:12.471 +00:00 [INF] Claim http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress  = someone@somewhere.com
2022-05-17 01:16:12.472 +00:00 [INF] Claim AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp  = OJLEYFWG4JE4ND5NRPTRT4JVCVEE2ANR
2022-05-17 01:16:12.473 +00:00 [INF] Claim http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role  = SuperAdmin
2022-05-17 01:16:12.475 +00:00 [INF] Claim http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences  = pwd
2022-05-17 01:16:12.477 +00:00 [INF] Claim nameid  = 7f041757-3aad-4221-971a-729598c1d81e
2022-05-17 01:16:12.478 +00:00 [INF] Claim email  = someone@somewhere.com
2022-05-17 01:16:12.480 +00:00 [INF] Claim role  = SuperAdmin
2022-05-17 01:16:12.481 +00:00 [INF] Claim amr  = pwd
```

The claim `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name` is **MISSING**. Instead we can see the claim called `name` holding the username value.

I tried to force the app to use the correct claim name

```
     options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name;
```

but that didn't work. Its still using the wrong name.

Pretty sure it is a simple configuration missing somewhere - if someone can point it out?

## UPDATE 1

I updated the code as follows

```
if (IsProduction)
{
     options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType =  'name';  
}
```

This actually worked and allowed the user to log in. Identity.IsAuthenticated == true and Identity.Name != null.
Hooray! ... But.. why??

Also, the following works in DEV on ASPNET 6 :

```
        [Inject]
        IHttpContextAccessor HCA { get; set; }

                if (HCA?.HttpContext?.User?.Claims?.Any() == true)
                {
                    foreach (var claim in HCA.HttpContext.User.Claims)
                    {
                        Logger.Log("HCA Type = {t} Value = {v}", claim.Type, claim.Value);
                    }
                }
```

But in Prod, on Azure App Services,  the check `HCA?.HttpContext?.User?.Claims?.Any() == true` **FAILS**. Meaning that there are no claims in HttpContext. How is that possible???

### ALSO

I  installed the ASP.NET core 6.0 (x64)  Extension to Azure Web App. It installed fine, but did not make a difference to authentication error.

## UPDATE 2

I found the source of the problem, but not the solution, yet.
It turns out that Azure Signal R is messing things up.

In Startup.cs I have this code:

```
            if (IsProduction)
            {
                services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(options =>
                {
                    options.ServerStickyMode = Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServerStickyMode.Required;
                });
            }
```

If I remove this, then the claims go back to normal, meaning:

- Name claim is now `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name`
- HttpContext works again

But of course I lose Azure SignalR which is no good.

What is even weirder is this:  I created a fresh ASPNET 6 Blazor Server App project using the "Local Authentication" template, and deployed that to Azure App Services. Now, the claims behaviour is slightly different:

- Name claim is correct `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name`
- A new claim called `unique_name`  is added to the ClaimsPrincipal
- HttpContext is broken.

| State | Name Claim | HttpContext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Upgraded ASPNET 5 Project; No Azure Signal R | OK | Working |
| Upgraded ASPNET 5 Project; **with** Azure Signal R | Broken | Broken |
| Fresh ASPNET 6 Project; **with** Azure Signal R | Working | Broken |

So, the upshot is:  Azure SignalR is definitely screwing up authentication for me. But why? And how do I fix it?

## Update 3

So, it turns out that the version of  [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt matters when using Azure Signal R.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1606#issuecomment-1132359990)

In the experiments above,

- the upgraded NET5>NET6 project was using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.10.0.20330  **(name claim wrong, unique_name claim missing)**
- the Fresh NET 6 project was using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.8.0.11012  (a lower version - strangely enough)   **(name claim OK, unique_name claim exists)**

To fix my problem, I simply upgraded to the latest
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt  6.18 and now authentication for my upgraded NET5 project works again.

To understand more, see [the github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1606)

PS. Kudos to the Azure SignalR team for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Pls add extension in kudu site, [I need to make sure you have install .net6 extension in azure webapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4mGs.png). I know azure webapp is running in sandbox environment, it should be support .net6. But I need to know what happened when you install the extensions.

Comment: That extension was not installed. I have now installed it. There does not seem to be any change to how it works.

Comment: TLDR;  My fix was to upgrade System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to 6.18 (v 6.10 doesn't work nicely with Azure Signal R)

Answer (score 3):

***Workaround:-***

When upgrading .NET5 to .NET6 project was using `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.10.0.20330` (name claim wrong, unique_name claim missing).

To resolve this upgrade to  the latest version of [**`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.18`**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) and then authentication for your upgraded `.NET5` project will works again.

P.S:- As `version 6.10` does not work properly with Azure Signal R.

For more information please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) & [***GitHub issue***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1606)

Comment: Thank you for this I ran into this problem as well.  I just want to add that I didn't have a direct reference to System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.  I was using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer (v 6.0.7) nuget package, which has a dependency on another library that depends on System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v 6.10.  A specific reference to the latest nuget package (6.21.0) solved this issue for me.